# Laravel 5.4 whereNotIn apparently not working

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have logic in a controller that builds an array called $exclude.

Using dd for $exclude I get :

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
  2 => 4
  3 => 5
]
```

which is correct.

I want to exclude those from a result so I have:

```
$potype = DB::table('potypes')
                ->whereNotIn('id',[$exclude])
                ->get();
```

but when I run the query those items are included with the exception of the first in the array. So I enabled the query log with

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

and ran

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

with the result of

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `potypes` where `id` not in (?)"
    "bindings" => array:4 [▼
      0 => 2
      1 => 3
      2 => 4
      3 => 5
    ]
    "time" => 0.67
  ]
]
```

The table has 8 records but running the query is returning 7, only ommiting the first of the list:

```
Collection {#621 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
```

If I use implode

$ex = implode(',',$exclude)
and change the query to
    ->whereNotIn('id',[$ex])
I get the same result - 7 items with just the first in the list being ignored.

Is this an Eloquent bug or me?

Answer (score 3):

delete `[ ]` and check it again:

```
$potype = DB::table('potypes')
                ->whereNotIn('id',$exclude)
                ->get();
```

Comment: I got -  ErrorException

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @JimElliott ```return dd($potype );``` to check if you get right query results, where is foreach code?

Answer (score -2):

OK it was realtively simple with Mohammed's comment pointing me in the right direction.

As `$exclude` was an `array` I changed the get to:

```
$potype = DB::table('potypes')
            ->whereNotIn('id',$exclude)
            ->get();
```

and it worked OK!

Comment: you should check my answer as accepted, not send it again as answer

Comment: I am sorry but they overlapped timewise